# Java applet hangs the vaadin application

Tags: java, applet, vaadin

I am working on vaadin web application in which I had used an applet which do some sound recording job. I used vaadin applet integration add-on to do so.

The applet runs fine on my computer, but it gives ClassNotFoundException on some other computer. I then installed the jre and JDK on that PC which I am using. Now when I try to open the applet. It hangs the application and the browser. So what can be the issue? I am unable to get the exact problem.
Thanks!

Comment: The other computers need the jars in their classpath if they are not packaged in the applet's jar.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved the issue!
The problem is because when the applet first time loaded in the browser, browser maintains the applet's jar file in its cache. Now every time when I try to load the applet, the browser loads it from its cached jar file and tries to look up for the class file in that jar, and when unable to find that, it gives this ClassNotFoundException.

So solution what I applied is, clear browser's cache, restart the browser, and run the applet. The applet will be working fine.